# Google Goelocation API for unsecured server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want Geolocation API to get the location access of browser on page load for unsecured server using PHP/ Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google doesn't allow to fetch Goelocation API for unsecured server.Earlier it used to but now it has completely restricted to use  Goelocation API for unsecured server.